# Remove A Domain From O365 Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I have read through this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/remove-a-domain?view=o365-worldwide

Seems very straightforward but like everything there are probably hidden caveats.

What are the impacts of removing a default domain from O365 on SharePoint Online (specifically) and other services?

Comment: Good question. I was always assuming it's not a good idea to remove the default domain in M365, but I have no idea what the real danger is.

Comment: This isn't even only about defaults domain removal either. It is also about if you have a linked on-premises domain in AD. It would be good to have more detailed information on any domain that is removed that has accounts attached and those accounts are moved.  Seems from the linked article they make it out to be easy but it doesn't specify if it does all the cleanup work behind the scenes.  For example, what happens to accounts that have permissions on ODFB or SharePoint Online sites?  Do they get moved automatically if they are first moved to a new domain?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions of user profiles in the old domain are **not** carried in the new domain automatically. Inheritance needs to be reconfigured after the migration.

See the reference here: [How SharePoint Migrate Users from One Domain to Another.](https://www.dataoutsource.com/blog/how-sharepoint-migrate-users-from-one-domain-to-another/)

If you have an on-premises Active Directory domain synced with Azure Active Director, either way, the sync needs [reconfiguration in Azure Active Directory Connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/sign-in/unable-remove-domain-office-365).

If you are in planning of removing the default domain, it is better that you contact Office 365 Support for assistance and potential risks that we are not aware of.

Here is another post that you can refer to for similar discussion: [Impacts of changing default domain in Office 365 tenancy?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/impacts-of-changing-default-domain-in-office-365-tenancy/m-p/200203)